# Code in Header to allow Subtome Button in Browser to find feed

Tags: browser, rss, subscription, rss-reader

By using the following code in header, I have managed for the rss button in url bar in browser to successful find my feed.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Blog Title" href="http://www.weeblysite.com/1/feed" />
```

However, the subtome button on browser fails to locate feed.  Therefore Feedly, Digg Reader, etc, finds no feed.

How can I implement code in my Weebly generated site to allow all such browser buttons to pick up and subscribe to feed?

Thank you.

Nicholas Boyd Crutchley

http://www.nicholasboydcrutchley.com/infin-story
this is a new blog.. no post...but the old blog has same problem..

Comment: May you share the URL for your site?

Comment: Sorry about that... been away for a while... [link](http://www.nicholasboydcrutchley.com/infin-story)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that your page has a broken discovery mechanism.
Right now in the `<head>` section of your HTML page, I can see this:

`<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='RSS 2.0' href='http:////feed' />`

And clearly, `http:////feed` is not the right feed url :) You want to have this:

`<link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='RSS 2.0' href='http://www.nicholasboydcrutchley.com/1/feed' />`

And everything should be smooth!